# How can I convert a user's string input such as 'int' or 'float' to types str and float?

Tags: python, input, types, type-conversion

I'd like know if there is a quick way to accept data types as a user input directly so I can use it directly to cast type on other variables?
I am not looking for conditionals or for loops to check for all possible options.
Thanks for the help in advance.
ex:

```
data_type = input('Enter a data type: str , bool, int or float: ')
```

user enters: `str`
I use datatype variable to change an integer to string type:   `datatype(234)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usage of eval is not recommended, but that solves your question:

```
data_type = eval(input('Enter a data type: str , bool, int or float: '))
```

But we also have a safer method than eval. That is using the `ast` library:

```
import ast
data_type = ast.literal_eval(input('Enter a data type: str , bool, int or float: '))
```

Comment: "eval" worked like a charm.  Also thanks for the fair warning about the use of eval. I did some research and will be cautious. "ast.literal_eval" never works for me for some reason throwing ValueError for even the simplest expressions.